# Unfamiliar syntax in two-variable functions, solving for C.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$ f (x, y) = c(x + y), x = 1, 2, 3, y = 1, . . . , x. $$

I'm sure this is a pretty basic question. I've done problems of this kind, solving for see before. But x and y have always been clearly defined I've not encountered this syntax before. 
What exactly does $$ x = 1, 2, 3, y = 1, . . . , x $$  mean?

I assumed it to mean Y took on every value X takes on - in this case, {1, 2, 3}

But that does not seem to be the case, since I'm getting an answer different from the book's.

Thanks to whomever points me in the right direction!

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with probability, its just algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Its saying that x ranges over the positive integers, and for any x, the function f(x,y) holds for $y\in \{1,2,3...x\}$.

Concrete example:

$f(3,y)$ is defined for $y=1,2,3$ but $f(3,4)$ makes no sense. Therefore, its saying that the domain of $f(x,y)$ is the set of integer pairs in the x-y plane where $x\leq y$.